# Repeater ITEM TEMPLATE colour

Tags: asp.net

In the repeater Item template, can i make the colour of alternate one difFerent.ie..1 blue next white,next blue,white...like that.

In this Item template i have a header division and Detail division.I want the Header division to have alternate colour like grid view.Is it possible..?
 thanks

```
    <ItemTemplate>


 <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header"
      onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none;">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="Groove" BackColor="#00D9D9">

    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "License")% 
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%


   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate")%
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Renewal")%>
  </asp:Panel> 
 </div>

 <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">

  <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Maroon">
  <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LicenseID"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="License Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseName")%>' Enabled="false" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>

             </asp:Panel>


 </div>

           </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Based on this code, you are going to have two tables within the header section of a third table? Maybe re-think your code, and use `<AlternatingItemTemplate>` for alternate lines.

Comment: sorry ,at first i pasted wrong code.Now i copied the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. See my answer. Also, you are missing `>`'s on some of your lines above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlternatingItemTemplate` to specify the format of alternating items. Here is a simple example:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
     <table border="1">
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
     <tr>
        <td style="background-color:Blue">
           <b><%# Container.DataItem %></b> 
        </td>
     </tr>
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
        <td style="background-color:White"> 
           <%# Container.DataItem %> 
        </td>
     </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
     </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.alternatingitemtemplate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header"
                onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none;">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="Groove" BackColor="#00D9D9">

                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "License")%>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>


                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate")%>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Renewal")%>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>

            <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">

                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Maroon">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LicenseID"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="License Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseName")%>' Enabled="false" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>

                </asp:Panel>


            </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header"
                onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none;">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="Groove" BackColor="#f0e68c">

                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "License")%>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>


                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate")%>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Renewal")%>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>

            <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">

                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Maroon">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LicenseID"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="License Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseName")%>' Enabled="false" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>

                </asp:Panel>


            </div>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>



    </asp:Repeater>
```